# Discord.py Ignore Error Handling if Custom Handler Already Exists

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

I have a Discord.py rewrite bot that sends a message to a certain channel on error via an `on_command_error` event.
I was wondering, if there was any way I could ignore my `on_command_error()` event, if the error is already handled in the `custom error handler` for that command.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the command called has an error handler via the [commands.Command.has_error_handler()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command.has_error_handler) method. Here is an example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    raise Exception("oops")

@my_command.error
async def handle_error(ctx, error):
    # handle the error

@bot.on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if ctx.command.has_error_handler():
        return  # since it has a custom error handler, do nothing here
    # if you reach this point, then there is no error handler
    # and you can handle it normally.
```

References:

- [ctx.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.command)
- [Commands.has_error_handler()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command.has_error_handler)

Comment: That checks for a custom error handler, but what if, say, I forgot to add MissingPermissions as an instance. How would I make my on_command_error event continue if there's an error the custom one didn't handle?